# Spring: cannot submit a form edit an entity have foreign key

Tags: spring, jpa

I hava an entity class Employee like this. It hava an object department (An other entity)

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Valid
    private String name;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Valid
    private Date date;

    private String cmt;

    private String address;

    private String position;

    private Boolean matrimony = true;

    @ManyToOne
    @Valid
    private Department department;
}
```

Controller, create controller show an edit page, and add controller solve adding request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String add(@Validated @ModelAttribute(value = "employee") Employee employee) {
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
    return "redirect:./list";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/create") 
public ModelAndView create(ModelMap mm) {   
    mm.addAttribute("action", "add");
    mm.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
    mm.addAttribute("dao", new DepartmentDAO(departmentRepository));
    return new ModelAndView("../jsp/employee/edit.jsp");  
}
```

View, It is form to input employee data and submit to add method.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${website_url}" commandName="employee">
            <form:hidden path="id"></form:hidden>
            <div class="form-group">
                Name:
                <form:input path="name" class="form-control"></form:input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Date of birth:
                <form:input path="date" class="form-control"></form:input>
            </div>                   
            <div class="form-group">
                ID card number:
                <form:input path="cmt" class="form-control"></form:input>
            </div>                   
            <div class="form-group">
                Address:
                <form:input path="address" class="form-control"></form:input>
            </div>                   
            <div class="form-group">
                Department:                     
                    <form:select path="department.id" class="form-control">
                        <% for(Department department : departmentDAO.departmentRepository.findAll()){%>
                            <form:option value="<%= department.getId() %>">
                                <%= department.getName() %>
                            </form:option>
                        <% } %>
                    </form:select>                      
            </div>                  
            <div class="form-group">
                Position:                      
                    <form:select path="position" class="form-control">
                        <form:option value="Director">Director</form:option>
                        <form:option value="Department Leader">Department Leader</form:option>
                        <form:option value="Employee">Employee</form:option>
                    </form:select>                      
            </div>                 
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                Matrimony:
                <form:checkbox path="matrimony" class="form-control"></form:checkbox>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary form-control" />
        </form:form>
```

I run spring and it load edit page correctly. But I submit form and I got a 400 Bad request, because of foreign key department.

Comment: Try changing your form action attribute to `action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employee/create"`

Comment: Yes, I have It in my code! If not, I will get 404 not found but 400 bad request.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Did your problem resolve???

Comment: I mean I have correctly "action" parameter. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA is most likely complaining about the fact that you're passing a detached `Department` entity to `persist`.

You should use a service method that will call something along the lines of `employee.setDepartment(departmentDAO.findById(employee.getDepartment().getId()))` and only then invoke `employeeRepository.save(employee)`.

Alternatively, you could probably add `cascade = MERGE` to your `@ManyToOne` and put a similar line of code in your controller, though it will not be safe transaction-wise.